# Notification Show An Empty Activity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sharedpreferences, android-notifications

I Wrote A Notification In my Project that Before Showing Notification , It Save Values In Shared Prefrences . It Work When App Is Open  and Show Info And My Values In Activity, But It Does Not Work When Application Is Close and When App Is Close And Notification Is shown and i Clicked in it, it Show that Activity Empty I Load Shared Pref Value in Oncreate Of That Activity must Show ... but it empty ...please help me  and when I click Back Button It Crashed...
my Notification code. it save value and show notification...

```
@Override
public void onSuccesResponse(JSONArray responseArray) throws JSONException {
    if (responseArray.length() > 0) {
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(apiManager.customer, apiManager.requesting, context);
        if (!G.onecNotify) {
            sharedPref.saveRequestData();
            sharedPref.loadRequestData();
            showNotification();
            G.notificationShown = true;
            requestListener.onResponseRequest(apiManager);
        }
    }
}
```

my main Notification Codes

```
   private void showNotification() {
    G.onecNotify = true;
    String[] infoToShow = new String[2];
    String sourceAddress = "  آدرس مبدا :" + apiManager.requesting.getSourceAddress();
    String destinetionAddress = " آدرس مقصد :" + apiManager.requesting.getDestinationAddress();
    String contentNotification = "";
    infoToShow[0] = sourceAddress;
    infoToShow[1] = destinetionAddress;
    for (int i = 0; i < infoToShow.length; i++) {
        contentNotification += infoToShow[i] + "\n\n";
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, RequestManagementActivity.class);
    Intent stackIntent = new Intent(context, MainAccountActivity.class);
    //PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = TaskStackBuilder.create(G.context)
            .addNextIntentWithParentStack(stackIntent)
            .addNextIntent(intent)
            .getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.whistle)
            .setContentTitle("شما درخواست ارسال بسته دارید")
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setColor(Color.parseColor("#ef9a9a"))
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND | Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS)
            .setLights(Color.parseColor("#e91e63"), 1, 1)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(contentNotification))
            .setContentText(contentNotification);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

and my activity must show . it load value and set in my activity controls

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_request_management);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    setTitle("");
    if (G.notificationShown) {
        apiManager = new ApiManager();
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(apiManager.customer, apiManager.requesting, G.context);
        sharedPref.loadCustomerData();
        sharedPref.loadRequestData();
        init();
        setControls();
    }
}
```

whwn app is close it show activity empty ..i need your help please help me ...:(

Comment: `(G.notificationShown)` What is this condition for?

Comment: I Removed 
 
(G.notificationShown) and it worked  . thank you so much